# Splitting polygons while keeping the same entry in attribute table

Tags: qgis, polygon, mapping

I have a map of several agricultural fields with unique data for each field.
I want to run some calculations per cultivated area based on the polygon layer.
Some fields have roads running through them which are not cultivated and shouldn't be calculated.

At the moment I have measured this area (headland) for each relevant polygon in a column in the attribute table. I then calculated polygon area and deducted the headland area from the total.

Is there a way to create 2 polygons that will act as one polygon (answer to the same row in the attribute table) so I can avoid the manual measurements?
Is there another way to do this more elegantly than manual measurements of each polygon headland?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a multipart polygon?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/52562/how-to-create-a-multipart-polygon)

Comment: Are your roads linear objects? You can create buffer polygons around roads and cut your agricultural polygons with these buffers. Result is multipart polygon layer as Cushen said.

Comment: My polygons already exist so instead of creating a multipart polygon I tried to split it to multiple parts. The issue is that it won't let me split it to more than 3 parts. When I split it further it deletes the first part. Any ideas?

Comment: Your question would greatly benefit by editing it to add screenshots and/or drawings that show a) what you have, and b) your desired results.